# fullpage.js scrollBar make it laggy on phone browsers

Tags: javascript, scroll, fullpage.js, mobile-phones

I am working on one page website which has a navigation on top and when user click on tabs it scrolls to certain section. I have a question about a line of code in javascript.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#fullpage').fullpage({
            anchors: ['main', 'about', 'products', 'cooking', 'stores', 'contact'],
            sectionsColor: ['#FFF', '#FFF', '#00652e', '#FFF'],
            scrollingBar:true,
            scrollingSpeed:1700
        });
    });
</script>
```

when I have **`scrollingBar: true`** in my code, website is not scrolling properly on phone browsers and if I remove it from the code it works perfect on mobile devices but I lose scroll on PC web browsers. Is there any fix for this matter?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The [demo page](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/scrollBar.html) with `scrollBar:true` seems to work fine on phones. Maybe the problem is that your site is full of huge images or similar.

When using `scrollBar:true` the plugin won't make use of  hardware acceleration as it does otherwise.

Comment: I removed scrollingSpeed and it works fine on mobile but I lost scrollbar on my page

Comment: I guess you mean `scrollBar`.